# If we let let explosives go off under one of the side of a skycraper, what will happen?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, explosions, building-physics

Imagine a skyscraper under which explosives are placed, but only beneath one of its sides. After detonation of the explosives, will the side under which the explosives were placed come crumbling down, and in the process pull the rest of the building along with it, so the whole building falls straight down? In a controlled demolition of a skyscraper, explosives are placed equally spaced beneath the building, after which it collapses straight down, so I'm pretty sure the building doesn't come falling down "nice and straight", but what will happen?

Off course it depends on the structure of the building, but let's assume that if the same explosives were placed under each side and corner the building comes falling straight down after the detonation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this should depend quite highly on the design of the structure in the building.  As it stands right now this seems too broad.

Comment: This seems more like an engineering question. What specific principles of Physics are you asking about?